# actualizar registro por dia

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de registro de asistencia.
Cuando el empleado inserta su id en una caja de texto nos registra la hora de entrada y envía dato nulo a la hora de salida, ahora para marcar la hora de salida simplemente actualizo el valor nulo a la hora en que se esta marcando la salida; eso es en un día , el problema esta en que al día siguiente al actualizar la hora de salida la hora de salida de ayer también se actualiza al de hoy, como resuelvo ese problema, por favor.

```
  private void UpdateHSalidaGA()
  {
        try
        {
            //instanciar la capa regla de negocio del personal
            RNPersona persona = new RNPersona();

            DataTable tablePersonne = new DataTable();

            string id = bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text.Trim();

            tablePersonne = persona.BD_LeerPersonnaNomPrenomGA(id);

            RNAssistance assistance = new RNAssistance();
            EnAssistance enAsistencia= new EnAssistance();

            string Asistencia = "Presente";
            //Debo instanciar la tabla de horario para saber si todos los campos estan llenos 

            enAsistencia.idEmploye = id;
            enAsistencia.heureSortie = DateTime.Now;
            enAsistencia.assistance = Assistea;
     
            assistance.RN_ActualisarHorarioSalidaGA(enAssistance);

            if (BDAssistance.Actualizado == true)
            {
                ContadorAtras();
          
                bunifuCustomTextbox1.Enabled = false;
                if (tablePersonne.Rows.Count == 0) return;

                label_NombreRegistado.Visible = true;
                label_Identification.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Visible = true;
                label_NombreRegistado.Text = Convert.ToString(tablePersonne.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
                label_Identification.Text = Convert.ToString(tablePersonne.Rows[0]["id"]);
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = " Enregistrement de sortie correct";
                //pictureBox_PhotoPerfil = Convert.ToString(tablePersonne.Rows[0]["photoperfil"]);
            }   
            else
            {
              
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreur est survenue" + ex.Message, "Avertissement de sécurité", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
               MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

Comment: el método RN_ActualisarHorarioSalidaGA() se conecta a alguna base de datos??. creo que allí deberías validar que el día del horario de entrada/salida sea igual al día actual, de esta forma no podrán marcar una entrada o salida fuera del día actual.

Comment: Y no estas guardando la fecha actual? Podrías actualizar el registro en base a ese campo

Comment: falta ver que haces en `RN_ActualisarHorarioSalidaGA`, ahi debe estar tu problema.

Comment: el RN_ActualizarHorarioSalidaGA no conecta a la base de datos,